# How to integrate Location based Augmented Reality in Android

Tags: android, vuforia, wikitude, android-augmented-reality

I have been searching seens long about augmented reality examples or documents which covers location based services.

For Example **i have to create such type of app which gives location based marker on camera view.Whenever i move camera to the direction of latitude and longitude i need to display AR marker on that direction.some thing like it is used to navigate user to that direction**.

There are many SDKs available for this like.

**GoogleCore**,
**Vuforia**,
**Wikitude**

But main problem of Google Core is it is not supported with all devices and i have also checked other example which needs compass sensor but which is also i dont want because compass sensor also not available in all devices

Also,I have searched in Vuforia and Wikitude but i am not getting how to display AR object with respect to latitude and longitude

There are lots off calculation available but i am not able to identify actual one to use.Please help if anyone knows about it

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: a device without the required sensors simply is not `AR` ready ...

Comment: ohk np but if you know how to achieve this using available sensor then please let me know.

Comment: this question is too broad... basically you would be looking to read values from `Sensor.TYPE_GEOMAGNETIC_ROTATION_VECTOR` or 
`Sensor.TYPE_GAME_ROTATION_VECTOR` and then update an `AR` overlay, according to the sensor readings.